# Need help in video calling app for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession, cmsamplebufferref

I am creating a simple video calling app where audio/video will stream from one device to other but problem is I don't know how video calling works especially how to get going with it in `iOS` .
   Until now I have captured video by using `AVCaptureSession` and used buffers from this delegate method

```
 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{}
```

For testing I have written the audio and video buffers to documents directory by using `AVAssetWriter`. After that I easily stored the video to iPhone gallery or played it with `MPMoviecontroller` player .

Now , I have following problems

1. I do not know how to send these buffers to server continuously  and then server to other device.
2. If I got successful in sending data to other device then how will I decode it to show video on other device .

   I have searched about it . like sending data through udp packets but I also do not know anything about it .

   If I get proper knowledge what to do then I am sure I will be able to do it . 
   Please provide me your views that what should i do to achieve this . I will be thankful to you for your help

Comment: Please also tell me if i am on right track by capturing buffers .

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok working perfectly.u can get tutorial at http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/documentation/gettingstarted

Comment: I have checked that and working but i want to start from scratch

Comment: I mean from starting without any 3rd party api